# How to display which function is being used using textview in android?

Tags: android

I want to have a layout which displays the message of which function in being currently used.

On running the code below it just shows me the latest TextView which is being used not all the `TextView`'s.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Created");
        linear.addView(tv);
        setContentView(linear);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Started");
        linear.addView(tv);
        setContentView(linear);    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Resumed");
        linear.addView(tv);
        setContentView(linear);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are changing the setContentView all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `setContentView` in every function. `setContentView` replaces the any previous defined view of `Activity`. You want to add `TextView` text on every function. So, you should set the content view in `onCreate` and then get the view and add the `TextView` in the `LinearLayout` you added in `onCreate`. Create the global linear layout and then use that just like below

```
LinearLayout linear;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Created");
    linear.addView(tv);
    setContentView(linear);
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Started");
    linear.addView(tv);
 }


@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Resumed");
    linear.addView(tv);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Activity class is,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView tvStart, tvCreate, tvResume;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvCreate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCreate);
    tvStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStart);
    tvResume = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResume);



    tvCreate.setText("Created");

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();Started

    tvStart.setText("Started");
}


@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

    tvResume.setText("Resumed");
}
}
```

xml for this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.technobd.stack.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCreate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResume"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

You can also add textviews dynamically like,
Activity class will be,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


LinearLayout llTextViews;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    llTextViews = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llTextViews);


    TextView tvCreate = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvCreate.setLayoutParams(params);
    tvCreate.setText("Created");

    llTextViews.addView(tvCreate);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    TextView tvStart = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvStart.setLayoutParams(params);
    tvStart.setText("Started");

    llTextViews.addView(tvStart);

}


@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

    TextView tvResume = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvResume.setLayoutParams(params);
    tvResume.setText("Resumed");

    llTextViews.addView(tvResume);
}
}
```

and xml layout is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.technobd.stack.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTextViews"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have just started coding in android , so I am not able to get the context of FindViewById .

Comment: its "findViewById" not "FindViewById"
remember Java is case sensitive.
In activity class you need to do nothing, just type as I wrote the code.

Comment: for the starters wanted something easy to understand.